# Isabelle simple double function

Tags: recursion, logic, isabelle

Im brand new to Isabelle, and HOL programming in general.
One of the exercises in a text book is to:

Define a recursive function double :: nat ⇒ nat and prove double m = add m m.

Im Still trying to define it but i can't figure it out.,
Here is what i have done so far.

```
fun double :: "nat => nat"  where
"double 0 = 0" |  //my base case
"double (n) =  //I don't know what to do here
```

I have a function add defined as follows.

```
fun add :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"add 0 n = n" |
"add (Suc m) n = Suc(add m n)"
```

but i don't think I'm meant to use add in the definition of double.
Also an explanation with the answer would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
Rainy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to figure out how to express `double (Suc n)` in terms of `double n` and `Suc`. That willl give you a recursive definition.

Comment: Would this be correct:                                                      fun double :: "nat => nat"  where
"double 0 = 0" |
"double (Suc n) = double n + Suc(Suc(0))"

Comment: In principle yes, but it is somehow cheating to use the built-in addition `op +` when the exercise is about `double` and `add`. Maybe you can express the same equation by just using `Suc`s without `op +` (or `add` for that matter)?

Comment: I changed it to "double (Suc n) = Suc(Suc(double n))" and i get no errors, is this correct then?

Comment: Yes. That was the intended result.